# How to set SLS_DEBUG in windows?

Tags: serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework , and getting the following error -

> For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

Which environment are they talking about ? How to set this ?
Am using windows 10.

Comment: `set SLS_DEBUG=*`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set it in your system environment variable.

For MacOS:
Open Terminal and type the following:

```
export SLS_DEBUG=true
```

For Windows:
Set it in the System Environment variable.

Comment: The `export SLS_DEBUG=true` command works for Linux as well. =D

Answer (score 9):

for powershell:

```
 $Env:SLS_DEBUG='true'
```

Answer (score 7):

For dummies like me who has been using Windows since the very start, but still doesn't know what

> For Windows: Set it in the System Environment variable.

means... a picture tells a thousand words...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SET export SLS_DEBUG=true in command prompt or set in System environment variable

Answer (score 0):

if you are using command prompt you can use:

SET SLS_DEBUG=true

then your sls command eg =

SET SLS_DEBUG=true

sls deploy --stage=dev